# How to determine unique characters in a string

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a solution in python to find the string having unique characters.

```
def is_unique_with_ascii(string):
    if len(string) > 128:
        return False
    char_set = [False] * 128

    for char in string:
        val = ord(char)
        if char_set[val]:
            print(char_set[val])
            return False
        char_set[val] = True
    return True
```

In this code, the char_set has been initialized with false values. But in if statement when the same character that has already in string caught the statement become true means the char_set[val] got true value.My question is in python how to  if char_set[val]: statement works to get the same value. Please help me out.

Comment: `if len(string)==len(set(string))`

Comment: Your code has a big bug, it will fail with any character having `ord` greater than 127.

Comment: What is exactly your question? Do you want to print the char that occures more than once?

Comment: If the string has unique characters the it will return true otherwise false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) for `if`, it evaluates the condition, which is `char_set[val]` in this case. Since it already returns a `Bool`, the `if` statement evaluates it right away, to give the impression that *"`if char_set[val]` statement works to get the same value"*

Comment: Okay I checked.